# workspace selector + mission control

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces

Is it possible to have something like the mac's mission control but working for all the workspaces? I mean: right now I can choose the workspace with `<super>s` and the windows inside a given workspace via `<super>w`. Is it possible to combine the behavior of the two commands? I wolud like to have a command, suppose `<super>z`, which shows me all the workspaces and all the windows inside the different workspaces.

I have Ubuntu 12.10.